# Java: convert to basic loop

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I'm just wondering how do I convert **for( char c: str.toCharArray())** to a simplified loop. I tried

```
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
```

However it doesn't seem to be working. Its a program to count the occurence of letters in a String. Btw this is not homework. Im just trying to practice to get back into the swing of things. Any guidance would be much appreciated.  Full code.

```
String str = "this is my new string";
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

    for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
    {
        char[] c = str.toCharArray();
        if(!map.containsKey(c))
            map.put(c,1);
        else
        {
            int value = map.get(c);
            map.put(c, ++value);
        }
    }
    System.out.println(map);
```

Comment: "However it doesn't seem to be working" is not a good/sufficient way to describe your problem.

Comment: Why do you `char[] c = str.toCharArray();` at each step of your loop?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the [String#charAt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) method:

```
for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++) {
    char c = str.charAt(i);
    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are actually using a whole array instead of just one element. You should take the transformation from string to character array out of the for loop and use c[i] in the loop.

Before, what you did was to check each time if the array formed of {'t', 'h', ...} is contained by your map instead of just checking for each character. 
The charAt() suggested by the others is a good way to do what you want without using extra variables.

```
String str = "this is my new string";
HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
char[] c = str.toCharArray();

for(int i = 0; i <= str.length(); i++)
{
    if(!map.containsKey(c[i]))
        map.put(c[i],1);
    else
    {
        int value = map.get(c[i]);
        map.put(c[i], ++value);
    }
}
System.out.println(map);
```

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for [`charAt(i)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt%28int%29) instead of `toCharArray()`.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent to what the compiler does for you here is

```
char[] chrs = str.toCharArray();
for(int i = 0; i < chrs.length; i++) {
   char c = chrs[i];
   // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(!map.containsKey(c))
```

Here c is a Character array not a Character. So you getting problem .

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
String str = "aabbccdefgh";

Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++) {
    Integer count = map.get(str.charAt(i));
    if (count == null)
        map.put(str.charAt(i), 1);
    else
        map.put(str.charAt(i), count + 1);
}
}
```

Try this.